# InputStream Reading Pattern

Tags: java, scala, sockets, inputstream, urlconnection

I am trying to use this code to find why does Java return an arbitrary number of reading bytes from inputStream.

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // 24 MB File
    val url = new URL("24 MB Sized Payload")
    // 25 MB File
    //    val url = new URL("25 MB Sized Payload")
    val connection = 
    url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 
    NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11")

    val inputStream = connection.getInputStream
    while(true) {
      val serializedData = new Array[Byte](1000)
      val count = inputStream.read(serializedData, 0, 1000)
      println(count)
    }
  }
}
```

So now when I am using url1 i.e. 25MB size payload then I am getting this

```
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
347
700
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
464
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

And when I am trying to read url2 i.e. 24 MB Payload the pattern for read bytes from inputStream is:

```
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
627
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
855
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

And this pattern is consistent across multiple runs for the same payload and across different JVMs ( more or less, there were slight differences in reading inputStream data pattern, but a very slight difference ) as well.

Does anybody has a clear explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Also nothing concrete seems to be visible from strace as there are no further system calls ( from jvm ) inspite of read on inputStream returning and issuing another read on inputStream, there were no in between system calls.

Comment: Why do you care? Pure intellectual curiosity, or something else?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087665/how-does-inputstream-read-in-java-determine-the-number-of-bytes-to-read). [Related Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-).

Comment: What is the sleep() call for?

Comment: Why do you declare an array of 10,000 bytes, then read just 1,000?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Just for the sake of analyzing and checking the strace but was of no use , also i have removed the sleep() and results are the same though.

Comment: @JBNizet Curiosity

Comment: @MikeAllen Just realized after seeing your comment, was experimenting with different array bytes size, but things still same behaviour holds and discrepancies between 24Mb and 25Mb.